# Can't get SPDY working on nginx 1.5.9

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, spdy

I can't get spdy to work after reinstalling Ubuntu. I'm using nginx 1.5.9 from the nginx launchpad repository which has spdy support build in. Snippet:

```
root@ssl:/etc/nginx/# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.5.9
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: …. --with-http_spdy_module ...
```

My vhost is configured as followed:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.key;

    location / {
     root /var/www;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  combined;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

- I already tried adding the spdy header (which shouldn't be necessary anymore) without luck
- The website loads fine
- My https certificate is valid, all browser give me a green lock-symbol
- SPDY doesn't work in the latest chrome or firefox

How can I further debug the spdy plugin? Any tips for further configuration?

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you have? Is there anything in nginx error log on startup or after the request?

Comment: I'm using 13.04. Here are the debug-logs for the vhost. Can't find anything spdy related in it though. http://pastebin.com/1HkGc7FS

Comment: Remember to get rid of 13.04. It's past end of support already.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Firefox & Chrome only support spdy 3, and nginx 1.5.9 still has spdy1/2. Upgrading to nginx/1.5.12 fixed my issue